# Fl Studio 12 no text?! Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine

Alright, So i installed FL Studio 12 Demo on Ubuntu 14.04 today, and to my surprise when i opened it up using wine, there where no drop down menu text. does anyone know how to fix this bug/issue? advice would be much appreciated! p.s (just ask if you need any system info) Thanks!

[image]

Comment: i have the same problem on 16.04 and putting a copy of the courier font in the c:\windows\fonts didn't work , neither did the winehq link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the `corefonts` package

To do this:

- Start winetricks
- Select the default wineprefix
- Choose 'install a font'
- Select 'corefonts' and click ok.

You will need to be online for the packages to be downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like font is missing. Download Courier(other) font and paste into you FL studio "font" folder.

**Download Courier font :** http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/C/Courier.html

**Source:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUQoHrqNKuk

Comment: im not exactly sure how to get to fl studio 'font' folder...

Comment: you need to search in /etc directory. 1. **cd /etc** 2. **ls -ltr**  and search for fl studio folder.   you may find here./FL Studio/Bottles/flstudio/drive_c/windows/fonts

Comment: Could i acces this folder By the terminal?

Comment: yes, you also need to download the font using wget command from terminal then unzip command. GUI would be nice.

Comment: ive searched every where in the ubuntu/wine directories but the folder 'Bottles' Is nowhere to be found!

Comment: just search for "font" folder or sub folders .

Comment: i added the fonts still no text :(

Comment: I guess you need to add "arial font". you can find arial font(**arial.ttf**) in your windows system "C:\Windows\Fonts" or you can download from internet.

Comment: alright ill try and add them.

Answer (score 1):

FL Studio 12 uses the Windows font "Arial" for its menus. It takes it from the windows fonts folder, which is located here: wine./drive_c/windows/fonts

All you have to do:

1. Download any .ttf font file from anywhere (but make sure it looks like arial, so that it's easily readable)
2. Copy it into the font folder (wine./drive_c/windows/fonts)
3. Rename it to arial.ttf

FL Studio will find and use it.
In my Wine installation, there were no fonts at all in this folder. I guess that's because the windows-fonts are not open source.

Answer (score 1):

For FL studio 20 (most probably each previous version will also do the job) - you can link system fonts to "windows" fonts folder with this one-liner:

```bsh
$ cd ${WINEPREFIX:-~/.wine}/drive_c/windows/Fonts && for i in /usr/share/fonts/**/*.{ttf,otf}; do ln -s "$i" ; done
```

On Arch/Manjaro - it worked out of the box - without trying any other solutions.